# issues with screen mirroring on windows 8.1 tablet

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-8.1, miracast

I am trying to implement screen mirroring onTV using a wifi dongle for windows 8.1 tablet. I used the projectionmanager class provided by microsoft, but for some reason its not able to detect the secondary display. Following is the code:

```
 bool available = ProjectionManager.ProjectionDisplayAvailable;

 ProjectionManager.ProjectionDisplayAvailableChanged += (s, e) =>
 {
       available = ProjectionManager.ProjectionDisplayAvailable;
 };

 int thisviewid = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
 // CoreDispatcher preseDispatcher= await ((App)App.Current).CreateNewView;
 ApplicationView appView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();

 CoreApplicationView view = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
 ApplicationView newAppView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
 await view.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,() =>
      {
          Window newWindow = Window.Current;

          var rootframe = new Frame();
          rootframe.Navigate(typeof(Projection),null);
          Window.Current.Content = rootframe;
      }
 ); 
 await ProjectionManager.StartProjectingAsync(newAppView.Id, appView.Id);
```

when I debugged the code, the ProjectionsDisplayAvailable value remains false. Not sure how to proceed on the same or make this working

Comment: Have you checked whether the Projection sample works on your system? https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Projection-sample-526b3c1d. This would help determine if it's a matter of hardware or a matter for your code. The sample is the right reference code in any case.

Comment: Hi Kraig, I tried checking that as well. The projection sample also doesn't work. the bool available = ProjectionManager.ProjectionDisplayAvailable; shows false unless it is connected through default windows option

Comment: In that case it sounds like there's an issue with how the display is being recognized by Windows at a lower level, and the APIs are just reflecting that. I don't think it's anything to do with the code. All I can think is that if the second display is set to duplicate the primary, then it's not reporting as a second projecting-capable display. It would have to be set to extend.

Comment: hmmmm... By any chance do you think if there is any issue with dongle? because dongle works with default Windows 8.1 functionality, but does not work correctly only through app

Comment: Not sure--maybe there is a driver issue--is it a USB dongle or HDMI? Another thing you can try is the Application Views sample (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Application-Views-98825022) which uses a different API to work with multiple monitors.